# WP Windows Phone Invalid XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I get exception

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in WP.MyOffice.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Unable to resolve property '%1' while processing
>   properties for Uid '%0'. [Line: 79 Position: 27]

[image]

1 - line 79 position 27

2 - "Invalid XAML" in Error List window

In Resources.recw has Hub.Header and HubSection1.Header

How found what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Check your resources.resw file, you probably have something like Hub.Text, while the "Hub" element doesn't support that attribute (text). Maybe you already used the key Hub for something else

Answer (score 1):

Strategy to fix:

1. Remove the `x:uid` properties and worry about localization later, get the `Hub` working.
2. If it still doesn't work create a basic hub with no items. Once working add the hub items/sections back until the point of failure.
3. Once the failure is determined resolve.